# Would it be unbalanced to let a 5e Cleric cast Enlarge/Reduce?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, balance

Playing D&D 5e. The Cleric (Tempest domain) in my players' 4th-level party (Cleric, Ranger, Rogue, Warlock) spotted Enlarge/Reduce and has taken a liking to it for hijinks of the Enormous Half-Orc or *really tiny halfling*.

However, Enlarge/Reduce isn't a Cleric spell. It's only on the Wizard and Sorcerer lists. Is there any balance reason Clerics shouldn't have it, or is it likely to just be flavour?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### You can do this in a balanced way

A single level 2 spell is not going to break your game. But there is a reason why the spell lists for different classes differ, and it is not balance: it gives them distinction, so they play differently and fill different roles, and play is more interesting and encourages a team working together.

Cleric domains already weaken the distinction and provide access to other spell lists. For example the Light domain even gives access to *fireball*, a signature spell for wizards and sorcerers -- but domains do so to support a theme. The Tempest domain likewise gives access to a lot of classical wizard spells, such as *lighting bolt* and *ice storm* -- but all these are thematically related to storms and weather. Enlarge/Reduce is not. You'll not affect balance in a major way by swapping out *gust of wind* or *shatter* with it. Shatter is a pretty decent area damage spell at third caster level, and can take out multiple weak foes. Swapping it out for *Enlarge/Reduce* will not make the character stronger.

This is supported by the *DMG*, page 287:

> **Modifying a class's spell list usually has little effect on
> a character's power but can change the flavor of a class significantly**. (...) Be cautious when changing the warlock spell list. Since warlocks regain their spell slots after a short rest, they have the potential to use certain spells more times in a day than other classes do.

So this is more a question of how gonzo and everything goes you like to play.  If you and your player are happy with it, go ahead.

Comment: That thought had crossed my mind, actually. His "deity" is certainly non-standard (he hears a voice in his head; even I, as DM, am not sure what it represents yet - but it is the reason he took Abyssal language proficiency at chargen...) so mixing up the domain isn't too wonky.

Comment: A complete answer should quote the DMG where it says that there are typically no balance issues with doing this except sometimes for warlocks.

Comment: I personally wouldn't do this without a narrative justification. The player doesn't have to know the justification up front, but **you** should. Maybe it's a gift that will need to be reciprocated. Maybe it's to deal with a certain challenge important for their deity 3, 5, 10 levels later. Maybe it's something else altogether. Either way, this is a great opportunity to tie a story to it.

Comment: There is a balance concern not described here, but that is implied in the solution. Expanding the main Cleric spell list would be a minor balance concern because it would add flexibility to the class at no cost (unlike for a Wizard or any other class that must limit its spells known). It is a small net gain in power for the class, in that having more options when choosing spells memorised is beneficial. So it is not just a thematic choice. By swapping out the domain spells you avoid this issue, because the number of choices and amount of flexibility that the character has is not increased.

Comment: @NeilSlater Exactly! Hence the title

Answer (score 0):

## The correct Backgrounds can grant a Cleric this spell.

The Simic Scientist background from Guildmaster's Guide to Ravnica and the Quadrix Student background from Strixhaven: A Curriculum of Chaos both grant the Enlarge/Reduce spell to characters that have taken them.

Additionally, a Cleric can qualify to take the Adept of Red Robes feat at level 4 if they've taken the Mage of High Sorcery background, from Dragonlance: Shadow of the Dragon Queen.